# Examples of mathematical ideas motivated by economics

Tags: soft-question, economics

Symplectic manifolds are motivated by classical mechanics as generalizations of phase space.
Are there any similar examples of interesting mathematical objects/areas of study which are motivated by economics?

Answer (score 1):

One such here - [Nonlinear dynamics in Economics](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540593744) and many more to dig around!

[John Nash and his contributions to game theory and economics](http://theconversation.com/john-nash-and-his-contribution-to-Game-theory-and-Economics-42355)